# Api plateform denormalization on custom operation problem

Tags: symfony, swagger, api-platform.com, denormalization

I have an entity Voucher that contain a custom operation name add_voucher:

```
<?php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={
 *          "add_voucher"={
 *                 "access_control"="is_granted('ROLE_COMMERCIAL')",
 *                 "method"="POST",
 *                 "path"="/vouchers/add-new",
 *                 "controller"=AddVoucherAction::class,
 *                  "denormalization_context"={
 *                      "groups"={"add_new_voucher"}
 *               },
 *                  "validation_groups"={"Default", "add_voucher_validation"}
 *         },
 *     }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\VoucherRepository", repositoryClass=VoucherRepository::class)
 */
class Voucher
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Groups("add_new_voucher")
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $code;
    /**
     * @Groups("add_new_voucher")
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $discount;
    /**
     * @Groups("add_new_voucher")
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     */
    private $starts_at;

    public function getDiscount()
    {
        return $this->discount;
    }
    public function setDiscount($discount): void
    {
        $this->discount = $discount;
    }
    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getCode(): ?string
    {
        return $this->code;
    }
    public function setCode(string $code): self
    {
        $this->code = $code;
        return $this;
    }
    public function getStartsAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->starts_at;
    }
    public function setStartsAt(\DateTimeInterface $starts_at): self
    {
        $this->starts_at = $starts_at;
        return $this;
    } 

}
```

I added the denormalization group to code,discount,starts_at, I Later to validate this columns in operations to do so I need to add it first in the denormalization context but in the swagger it show only
the code and discount properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the spelling combination of your **$starts_at** property and **getStartsAt()** getter. Basically, Symfony serializer use yours getters to access private properties.

Just replace either your property by **$starstAt** or add an underscore to your getter.

Take a look at [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html#adding-normalizers-and-encoders);

Comment: I tried adding underscore to the getter method like this : getStarts_At but it won't work, I changed the property name to starstAt and it works ! Thanks :)